# How to decrease the interval levels in R

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
CASE        DEGREE       INCOME SLAB

1          Graduate       $1000-$2000

2          High School   $2000- $3000
```

so on..

For the degree category I have four levels but for Income slab I have 20+ levels. These 20+ levels are in the range of $1000. I want to decrease it to say 10 or less by the range of $10000. like $1000-$10000,  $10000-$20000 so on. How can I do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ori = c('$1000-$2000','$3000-$4000','$5000-$6000','$7000-$8000','$9000-$10000')
> ddf = data.frame(ori)
> ddf
           ori
1  $1000-$2000
2  $3000-$4000
3  $5000-$6000
4  $7000-$8000
5 $9000-$10000
> 
> ddf$ori = gsub('$','',ddf$ori, fixed=T)
> ddf
         ori
1  1000-2000
2  3000-4000
3  5000-6000
4  7000-8000
5 9000-10000

ddf$min = lapply(strsplit(ori, '-'), function(x)x[1])
> ddf
         ori  min
1  1000-2000 1000
2  3000-4000 3000
3  5000-6000 5000
4  7000-8000 7000
5 9000-10000 9000
> 
> ddf$new = ifelse(ddf$min<5000, '$1000-$5000', ifelse(ddf$min<10000,'$5000-$10000','$10000-$15000' ))
> ddf
         ori  min          new
1  1000-2000 1000  $1000-$5000
2  3000-4000 3000  $1000-$5000
3  5000-6000 5000 $5000-$10000
4  7000-8000 7000 $5000-$10000
5 9000-10000 9000 $5000-$10000
>
```